# CORS with Aurelia-CLI server

Tags: aurelia

**Updated solution and history of problem**

My setup is like this:

[image: setup]

I had CORS understood the wrong way around, thinking that the HTTP server should serve the headers. The fact is that it is the 3rd party API which needs to supply CORS headers.

As the 3rd party doesn't send CORS headers, and `fetch client` expects those (to get around same-origin policy of browsers) an error message like this appears:

> Fetch API cannot load http://api.sl.se/api2/realtimedeparturesV4.json?key=b99d17e1714142ca90ed017aeead32fc&siteid=9001. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

Now, there are possibilities to turn of CORS in the fetch client with `{mode: 'no-cors'}`, but that prohibits JavaScript (unless response is plain text).

The solution, I chose is to implement a proxy on the server-side (for simplicity: same domain as the Aurelia page is served from) which then calls the 3rd party. Server-side doesn't have CORS restrictions.

A better solution would be that the 3rd party supported CORS, but sometimes this is not an option (i.e. 3rd party).

Comment: Nope. It's the API that needs to send CORS headers.

Comment: If you post more details about your API setup, maybe we can help. But it's definitely not related to Aurelia-CLI.

Comment: more details are posted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aurelia Fetch client's default is CORS, so your Aurelia app should definitively be able to fetch from 3rd party servers.
Your API endpoints, not your Aurelia Cli server, are probably not sending the right headers back to the browser (your Aurelia app) in preflight requests needed for CORS to be working. What headers of course depend on the content that you are trying to send and receive from and to your endpoints.

Comment: I've added the code, including URL for API endpoint (open endpoint). My understanding of CORS is that it is the server which serves the initial Aurelia app that is to send headers (who to browser is allowed to contact), but I'm beginning to think that's wrong.